# Ember CLI - Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, module, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

I am converting an old school Ember app (built with grunt) into Ember CLI, and I'm facing an odd issue I can't seem to resolve.

When I launch the app with `Ember serve` and access it in the browser, I get two errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module handlebars
Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember
```

I have no clue on what to look for as I'm importing handlebars and ember in Broccoli, supposedly with the right syntax.

Here is my `Broccoli.js`:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp();

app.import('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
app.import('bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js');
app.import('bower_components/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js');
app.import('bower_components/recaptcha-ajax/recaptcha_ajax.js');
app.import('bower_components/noty/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.js');
app.import('bower_components/d3/d3.min.js'); 
app.import('vendor/noty/noty-custom-theme.js');

app.import({
    development: 'bower_components/ember/ember.js',
    production:  'bower_components/ember/ember.prod.js'
 });

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

In the app I import Ember using standard ES6 syntax:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   ...
});
```

Here is what by bower list looks like:

```
application
├─┬ bootstrap-sass-official#3.3.1
│ └── jquery#2.1.1
├── d3#3.4.13
├─┬ ember#1.9.0-beta.4
│ ├── handlebars#2.0.0
│ └── jquery#2.1.1
├─┬ ember-c3#0.1.3
│ ├─┬ c3#0.4.5 (0.4.7 available)
│ │ └── d3#3.4.13
│ ├── ember#1.9.0-beta.4
│ └── handlebars#2.0.0 incompatible with ^1.3.0 (1.3.0 available, latest is 2.0.0)
├─┬ ember-cli-shims#0.0.3
│ └── ember#1.9.0-beta.4
├── ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4
├─┬ ember-data#1.0.0-beta.12
│ └── ember#1.9.0-beta.4
├─┬ ember-load-initializers#0.0.2
│ └── ember#1.9.0-beta.4
├─┬ ember-qunit#0.1.8
│ ├── ember#1.9.0-beta.4
│ └── ember-data#1.0.0-beta.12
├─┬ ember-qunit-notifications#0.0.4
│ └── qunit-notifications#0.0.3
├─┬ ember-resolver#0.1.10
│ └── ember#1.9.0-beta.4
├── fontawesome#4.2.0
├─┬ fuelux#3.3.1
│ ├─┬ bootstrap#3.2.0 (latest is 3.3.1)
│ │ └── jquery#2.1.1
│ ├── jquery-1.11.0#1.11.0 (latest is 2.1.1)
│ ├── moment#2.7.0 (latest is 2.8.4)
│ └── requirejs#2.1.15
├── handlebars#2.0.0
├── jquery#2.1.1
├─┬ jquery-validation#1.13.1
│ └── jquery#2.1.1
├── loader.js#2.1.1
├── noty#2.3.2
├── qunit#1.15.0
└── recaptcha-ajax#ea58c14d98
```

I tried:

- Changing the order in which I import things in broccoli (should make no difference but was worth a try)
- Importing handlebars.runtime instead
- Reinstaling ember-cli with `npm uninstall -g ember-cli && npm cache clear && npm install -g ember-cli#0.12` - no luck...
- Performing the steps here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/10/16/handlebars-update.html#toc_ember-cli-steps

Here are the versions:

```
$ ember version --verbose
version: 0.1.2
http_parser: 1.0
node: 0.10.33
v8: 3.14.5.9
ares: 1.9.0-DEV
uv: 0.10.29
zlib: 1.2.3
modules: 11
openssl: 1.0.1j
npm: 2.1.3
```

What is going on?

I also opened an issue with ember-cli here:
https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2636

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you update an existing ember-cli? If so try removing it with 'npm uninstall -g ember-cli' and reinstalling it. After that try creating a new project.

Comment: You don't need to import ember and handlebars they come packed with the ember-cli

Comment: That's what I thought, I added them after getting these errors since they seemed to be missing.. removing them makes no difference for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that was a bug on Ember CLI 0.1.3. I opened a ticket here:
https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2636

Version 0.1.4 also doesn't work on Windows due to other bug on Windows.

If you encounter this, use version 0.1.2 (which works) or try a more recent one if that exists when you hit the issue.